# at not executing scheduled command - troubleshooting

Tags: bash, shell-script, at

I am writing this bash script, that will read a file containing a date, a time and a phone number, and it will use an SMS provider API to send an sms reminder.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read date time phone
do

user=user
pass=pass
senderid=senderid
message=Your%20appointment%20is%20at%20$date%20$time.%20For%20cancellations%20call%2096989898.%20Thank%20you.
api="https://sms.service.com/Websms/sendsms.aspx?User=$user&passwd=$pass&mobilenumber=357$phone&message=$message&senderid=$senderid&type=0"

curl -k $api

done < ~/sms_reminders/events/events_$(date +%d-%m-%y)
```

When I run it like this, I receive an SMS immediately. But I want to schedule the reminder to go out at a specific time. So I change the script to this.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read date time phone
do

user=user
pass=pass
senderid=senderid
message=Your%20appointment%20is%20at%20$date%20$time.%20For%20cancellations%20call%2096989898.%20Thank%20you.
api="https://sms.service.com/Websms/sendsms.aspx?User=$user&passwd=$pass&mobilenumber=357$phone&message=$message&senderid=$senderid&type=0"

echo curl -k $api | at $time

done < ~/sms_reminders/events/events_$(date +%d-%m-%y)
```

And I get a message saying

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 22 at Fri Jun  6 21:46:00 2019
```

Which is good.

But I never receive the SMS.

My guess is that the issue has something to do with sh, but I have no way of being sure because at doesn't really generate a log file saying if the command was completed successfully or not.

Comment: Is the date and time correct in the output of the `at` command? The date and time that you show has not occurred anywhere on the planet yet.

Comment: yeah that was a typo. The date is correct.

Comment: Have a look at whatever log file cron writes to and see if `atrun` or similar process executes your scheduled jobs. I'm assuming that `atq` does not show the jobs any longer?

Comment: the unquoted `$api` contains `&` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameter expansion to tell Bash to quote the `api` variable:

> **`${parameter@operator}`**
>   The expansion is either a transformation of the value of parameter or
>   information about parameter itself, depending on the value of
>   operator. Each operator is a single letter:
>
> - `Q`  The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

So:

```
echo curl -k "${api@Q}" | at "$time"
```

If you escape the quotes like in `echo curl -k \"$api\"`, then the expansion of `api` will undergo field splitting and wildcard expansion, which might cause problems depending on the content. So it's better to have it quoted normally `"${api}"`, and tell bash to quote it again for input using `"${api@Q}"`.

For reference, with the example input, the output is:

```
$ echo curl -k "${api@Q}"
curl -k 'https://sms.service.com/Websms/sendsms.aspx?User=user&passwd=pass&mobilenumber=357&message=Your%20appointment%20is%20at%20%20.%20For%20cancellations%20call%2096989898.%20Thank%20you.&senderid=senderid&type=0'
```

Note the single quotes added around the URL in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I had no idea I could do it like that. Won't the single quotes be a problem? I have variables in the URL and if I'm not mistaken, double quotes are needed for the variables to be parsed.

Comment: it actually worked like a charm. I like that it's more tidy now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it like this

```
echo curl -k \"$api\" | at $time
```